# iterate over argument list in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

I want to iterate over the argument list in shell, I know how to do this with

```
for var in $@
```

But I want to do this with

```
for ((i=3; i<=$#; i++))
```

I need this because the first two arguments won't enter into the loop. Anyone knows how to do this? Looking forward to you help.

cheng

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might help:

```
for var in "${@:3}"
```

for more information you can look at:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-parameters/index.html

Answer (score 4):

[reader_1000 provides a nice bash incantation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620478/iterate-over-argument-list-in-linux-shell/7620536#7620536), but if you are using an older (or simpler) Bourne shell you can use the creaking ancient (and therefore highly portable)

```
VAR1=$1
VAR2=$2
shift 2
for arg in "$@"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old question, there is another way you can do this.  And, maybe this is what you are asking for.

```
for(( i=3; i<=$#; i++ )); do  
    echo "parameter: ${!i}"  #Notice the exclamation here, not the $ dollar sign.
done
```